# What is Git's command line diff and log viewer?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

When calling `git log` or `git diff` in the terminal the result is displayed using some kind of viewer. I know how to navigate, quit and search for keywords but wanted to have some background on what I am actually doing. What is this viewer's name and where is this viewer documented?

I know the editor goes to my default text editor but this "viewer" seems to be something else. I have been looking for it for a while but I am not sure I am searching using the correct keywords.

Comment: It uses your default pager.

Answer (score 3):

The default viewer for git is [`less`](https://www.gnu.org/software/less/). You can change it to something else (e.g., `more`) by setting the `code.pager` config value. E.g.:

```
$ git config --global core.pager more
```

You can find out more in the [Git Configuration documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Comment: "less" was written as an improved "more" that allowed you to scroll around the displayed text, it is not recommended to replace `less` with `more`  IMHO.

Comment: @gzh I just gave `more` as an example of a pager that *could* be used, just to show how the `core.pager` config value works. I agree it isn't a very good choice. Could you suggest a better example please?

Comment: less is enough for me, with scroll, syntax highlight, and warning color for whitespace at EOL, almost installed in every linux PC, I do not want to change it. For complex difference and comparing, I would like to resort to `git difftool`.

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you, I was in this doc page but somewhat lost on what to look for. `core.pager` solves the problem for me and i will read more into `less`.

Answer (score 1):

git use `less` for default viewer, you can look [manpage of less](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) to find how to search in it.

Answer (score 1):

The default viewer is `less`:

> **core.pager**
>
> Text viewer for use by Git commands (e.g., *less*). The value is meant to be interpreted by the shell. The order of preference is the `$GIT_PAGER` environment variable, then `core.pager` configuration, then `$PAGER`, and then the default chosen at compile time (usually *less*).
>
> When the `LESS` environment variable is unset, Git sets it to `FRX` (if `LESS` environment variable is set, Git does not change it at all). If you want to selectively override Git’s default setting for `LESS`, you can set `core.pager` to e.g. `less -S`. This will be passed to the shell by Git, which will translate the final command to `LESS=FRX less -S`. The environment does not set the `S` option but the command line does, instructing less to truncate long lines. Similarly, setting `core.pager` to `less -+F` will deactivate the `F` option specified by the environment from the command-line, deactivating the "quit if one screen" behavior of `less`. One can specifically activate some flags for particular commands: for example, setting `pager.blame` to `less -S` enables line truncation only for git blame.
>
> Likewise, when the `LV` environment variable is unset, Git sets it to `-c`. You can override this setting by exporting `LV` with another value or setting `core.pager` to `lv +c`.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: _pager_ is the exact word I was looking for, thank you!